# MERN App Deployed to Heroku, Posts on page render invisible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

App works flawlessly locally. I have had lots of trouble getting it deployed correctly to Heroku. Using Mongodb Atlas, Heroku, and Express. It's a basic Forum app that appends posts to the page from the databse. It's correctly hitting the database and the posts get returned and they're EVEN THERE! But they are invisible, yet still clickable. I have no idea what is causing this. ANY IDEAS WELCOME

[Github Repo](https://github.com/schoess/Open_Forums)
[Deployed Heroku App](https://open-forums-schoess.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that in the css file correlating to the missing posts, the opacity value was set as a percentage. It was fine running locally, but when deployed, it defaulted to an opacity of 1%, making it seem like they were missing. After changing the value to a decimal, it works as intended.